# Combine 10 cycles into one in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cycle

Here's my code with cycles and **I want to make it shorter (in one cycle if possible).**

```
 function plan(piece) {

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            piece.addStep('right');
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            piece.addStep('down');
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            piece.addStep('left');
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            piece.addStep('up');
        }
    }
```

etc... to i < 1

I thought about it that case,

```
   function plan(piece) {
     for (i=10; i>1; i--){ 
         piece.addStep('right');
         piece.addStep('down');
         piece.addStep('left');
         piece.addStep('up');
     }
```

but it's was wrong. Help pls!

here's look of task(maze)

[image: here's look of task(maze)]

Comment: does the order matter? is `piece.addStep('right'); piece.addStep('right'); piece.addStep('down');` the same as `piece.addStep('right');  piece.addStep('down'); piece.addStep('right');`?

Comment: You want to call piece.addSteps('right') 10 times piece.addSteps('down') 9 times and so on? And does the order matter to you?

Comment: So you want `piece.addStep('right');` to be done 10 times, `piece.addStep('down');` 9 times etc?

Comment: Is it homework?

Comment: It's not the problem (it could easily be the *next* problem), but: That code is falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*. Declare your variables in the appropriate scope. Not declaring them, in loose mode, makes them globals.

Comment: @Nina Scholz yes, it's matter. I've updated a post with a picture.

Comment: Your two code examples produce two totally different outputs.

Comment: if you are adding the items to an array object, there are a bit shorter alternatives

Answer (score 3):

You can add function for the repeating logic :

```
function addSteps(piece, n) {
    while (n--) {
        piece.addStep(piece);
    }
}

addSteps('right', 10);
addSteps('down', 9);
addSteps('left', 8);
addSteps('up', 7);
```

Comment: I like this answer, as it's more general than the nested loops that only work with this specific spiral.

Answer (score 1):

Simply combine all of them by introducing some if Checks.

**For Example :**

```
function plan(piece) {

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            piece.addStep('right');
            if(i < 9)
              piece.addStep('down');
            if(i < 8)
              piece.addStep('left');
            if(i < 7)
              piece.addStep('up');
        }
 }
```

Comment: Thx, but it will be still a lot of strings of code. How to make it shorter? To automate i decrementing?

Comment: @MR unless you're out code golfing, it's really not going to need to be smaller. If it were to be made smaller, it would be hard to read. Write for humans first and machines second :)

Comment: @MR There may be definitely a better way to do it, this solution is posted  to make it more readable and understandable, and to keep the complexity as low as possible,  :-)

Answer (score 1):

One option is:

```
function plan(piece) {
   ['right', 'down', 'left', 'up'].forEach((dir, ind) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 10 - ind; i++) {
         piece.addStep(dir);
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: The best possible way.

Answer (score 0):

You could take nested loops and increment the index for getting the right direction.

```js
var sequence = ['right', 'down', 'left', 'up'],
     i, j,
     k = 0,
     l = sequence.length;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (j = i; j < 10; j++) {
        document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += sequence[k] + '\n';
        // or piece.addStep(sequence[k]);
    }
    ++k;
    k %= l;
}
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doubt it is efficient, but you can be Array fill, concat, and forEach

```
var steps = [].concat(Array(10).fill("right"), Array(9).fill("down"), Array(8).fill("left"), Array(7).fill("up"))
steps.forEach(dir => piece.addStep(dir));
```